# Executing resulting rows for the result of Dynamic Native SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, native

I'm going mental over this.  I'm fairly new to dynamic SQL, so I may just not be asking Google the right question, but here's what I'm trying to do...  I have a query with dynamic SQL.  When I run that query, it produces several rows.  All of these rows (about 30) make up a single union query.  I can copy all of those rows and paste into a new query and run - works fine, but what I need to do is run this all in a single query.  I've looked up examples of using execute immediate and fetch, but I cannot seem to get them to actually spit out the data...they just end up saying something like "Executed Successfully", but doesn't actually produce any resulting rows.  The resulting column name of the below SQL is "qry_txt" - instead of producing it at face value, I want to execute it as a query.  Again, I may not be articulating this well, but I'm basically trying to turn 2 queries (with a manual copy/paste step involved) into a single query.  Hope this makes sense...

Here's my SQL:

```
Select CASE when 
lead(ROWNUM) over(order by ROWNUM) is null then
'SELECT '||''''||T.TABLE_NAME||''''||' as TABLE_NAME,'||''''||T.COLUMN_NAME||''''||' as COLUMN_NAME, cast('|| T.COLUMN_NAME ||' as 
varchar2(100)) as SAMPLE_DATA ||
from rpt.'||T.TABLE_NAME ||' where '||T.COLUMN_NAME||' is not null and ROWNUM=1;'  
else
'SELECT '||''''||T.TABLE_NAME||''''||' as TABLE_NAME,'||''''||T.COLUMN_NAME||''''||' as COLUMN_NAME, cast('|| T.COLUMN_NAME ||' as 
varchar2(100)) as SAMPLE_DATA from rpt.'||T.TABLE_NAME ||' where '||T.COLUMN_NAME||' is not null and ROWNUM=1 union ' end as qry_txt
from all_tab_columns t where T.OWNER='rpt' and T.DATA_TYPE != 'BLOB' and T.DATA_TYPE != 'LONG' and T.TABLE_NAME = 'NME_DMN' 
ORDER BY ROWNUM asc;
```

Comment: Is your goal to open a cursor that gets returned to a caller that then fetches the rows (that's easier and can be done via `execute immediate`).  Or do you need a PL/SQL block that fetches all the rows (which is harder and almost certainly involves a more complex route using the `dbms_sql` package)?

Comment: From what I've been reading, opening a cursor sounds like the right track.  Yes, I need to fetch all of the rows as if I'm running a straight select query.  So long as I end up with the rows, I'm open to either method, but the easiest would be best in terms of my being able to repeat the technique... ;)

Comment: If you want to open a cursor that gets returned to the caller, the caller can't be a PL/SQL block that fetches the data (well, it could if you're using 12.1 and you're willing to get even more complicated).  You could return a cursor to, say, `SQL*Plus` or a C# application which could then fetch the data.  If you want to have a PL/SQL block that fetches all the rows, you're going to need the more complicated `dbms_sql` path.  I'm not sure which of these actually works for you.

Comment: I'd say, if it's not a feature of native sql in oracle (out of the box), then it probably wouldn't work for me.  All of the dbms_sql examples I've come across fail for me.  So, maybe opening a cursor isn't the answer?  Do you see any other out of the box method I can use to achieve what I want?  This is my first attempt at something like this, so maybe it's not even possible.  From the results I'm seeing on Google, I'm the first person on the planet trying to do this, so maybe it's not doable...

Comment: It's eminently do-able.  Using `execute immediate`, you can happily return a cursor to an application that knows how to interrogate the cursor to determine things like the number and type of the columns in order to fetch the data.  `SQL*Plus` knows how to do that as does, realistically, any client API (JDBC/ ODBC/ OLE DB/ etc.).  If you want to write a PL/SQL block that fetches the data, then you need to write more complicated `dbms_sql` code.  Both `execute immediate` and `dbms_sql` exist "out of the box".  One is just much simpler than the other.

Comment: Can any of these methods utilize the SQL I've already written?  Or are you saying it will require a complete rework?  Can you point me to any examples where someone is doing what I'm describing?  Writing the first part of my SQL went very smoothly, so it seems like an equally accessible method should exist to execute the results...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125527/discussion-between-justin-cave-and-user3108489).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write a dynamic query in a SQL. You need to use PLSQL block to accomploish that. Please see how you can do it. 
PS: Code is not tested.

```
declare
  var1 <decalration same of column in select list> ;
  var2 <decalration same of column in select list> ;
  var3 <decalration same of column in select list> ;
  ....
  varn   ;

 begin
  for i in ( SELECT LEAD (ROWNUM) OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM) COl1
              FROM all_tab_columns t
               WHERE     T.OWNER = 'rpt'
                     AND T.DATA_TYPE != 'BLOB'
                     AND T.DATA_TYPE != 'LONG'
                     AND T.TABLE_NAME = 'NME_DMN'
             ORDER BY ROWNUM ASC)

  Loop

     If i.col1 IS NULL Then

     execute immediate   'SELECT '
                           || ''''
                           || T.TABLE_NAME
                           || ''''
                           || ' as TABLE_NAME,'
                           || ''''
                           || T.COLUMN_NAME
                           || ''''
                           || ' as COLUMN_NAME, cast('
                           || T.COLUMN_NAME
                           || ' as 
                              varchar2(100)) as SAMPLE_DATA ||
                            from rpt.'
                           || T.TABLE_NAME
                           || ' where '
                           || T.COLUMN_NAME
                           || ' is not null and ROWNUM=1' into var1 , var2 ,var3 ....varn;

    Else

       execute immediate  'SELECT '
                           || ''''
                           || T.TABLE_NAME
                           || ''''
                           || ' as TABLE_NAME,'
                           || ''''
                           || T.COLUMN_NAME
                           || ''''
                           || ' as COLUMN_NAME, cast('
                           || T.COLUMN_NAME
                           || ' as 
            varchar2(100)) as SAMPLE_DATA from rpt.'
                           || T.TABLE_NAME
                           || ' where '
                           || T.COLUMN_NAME
                           || ' is not null and ROWNUM=1' into var1 , var2 ,var3 ....varn;

    end if;

  End Loop;             

  exception
   when others then
   dbms_output.put_lin(sqlcode ||'--'||sqlerrm);

End;
```

Comment: I ran this and received this error:  Lookup Error
ORA-06550: line 2, column 8: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "<" when expecting one of the following: constant exception table long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national character nchar

Comment: I just help you the body. Its not a actual working code. I just helped you the way you can work on . Also my comments are inlined. Just follow the syntax and modify your code accordingly

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough about your technique or the errors I'm receiving, currently, to make this work for me.  Still trying...

Comment: You can post the code you are trying. Either me or someone will surely help you out. forget not to tag the question under Oracle and post the error you faced

Comment: I modded: 
declare
  var1 <decalration same of column in select list> ;
  var2 <decalration same of column in select list> ;
  var3 <decalration same of column in select list> ;
to
declare
  var1 declaration same of column in select list ;
  var2 declaration same of column in select list ;
  var3 declaration same of column in select list ;

Removed "<>" and changed "decalration" to "declaration".  Now error: Lookup Error
ORA-06550: line 2, column 20: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SAME" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; not null range default character

Comment: I can feel that you do not know PLSQL at all. In that case it would be difficult for me to answer.

Comment: I have never used a procedure in SQL.  So, if this is what you mean, then you are correct.  However, I pick things up fast, so don't lose faith in me that quick!

Comment: Please read this . https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm

Comment: I get the concept, I just haven't done it nor do I understand how that ties to my current question.  Are you saying what I want is possible through a procedure?

Comment: I modified your code and now it runs, but it just says "executed successfully"  It doesn't actually return rows.  Code here: http://pastebin.com/XJLnb9Zi

Comment: Post your working code as a question and close this one . Am happy to see that you learned really fast

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125532/discussion-between-user3108489-and-xing).

Comment: Chat is disabled here..Am very very sorry/